# Python Multithreading a for loop with limited Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

i am just learning Python and dont have much expierence with Multithreading. I am trying to send some json via the Requests session.post Method. This is called in the function at the bottem of the many for loops i need to run through the dictionary.

Is there a way to let this run in paralell?

I also have to limit my numbers of Threads, otherwise the post calls get blocked because they are to fast after each other. Help would be much appreciated.

```
def doWork(session, List, RefHashList):
    for itemRefHash in RefHashList:
        for equipment in res['Response']['data']['items']:
            if equipment['itemHash'] == itemRefHash:
                if equipment['characterIndex'] != 0:
                    SendJsonViaSession(session, getCharacterIdFromIndex(res, equipment['characterIndex']), itemRefHash, equipment['quantity'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, structuring your code differently might improve the speed without the added complexity of threading.

```
def doWork(session, res, RefHashList):
    for equipment in res['Response']['data']['items']:
        i = equipment['itemHash']
        k = equipment['characterIndex']
        if i in RefHashList and k != 0:
            SendJsonViaSession(session, getCharacterIdFromIndex(res, k), i, equipment['quantity'])
```

To start with, we will look up `equipment['itemHash']` and `equipment['characterIndex']` only once.

Instead of explicitly looping over `RefHashList`, you could use the `in` operator. This moves the loop into the Python virtual machine, which is faster.

And instead of a nested `if`-conditional, you could use a single conditional using `and`.

*Note:* I have removed the unused parameter `List`, and replaced it with `res`. It is generally good practice to write functions that only act on parameters that they are given, not global variables.

Second, how much extra performance do you need? How much time is there on average between the `SendJsonViaSession` calls, and how small can this this time become before calls get blocked? If the difference between those numbers is small, it is probably not worth to implement a threaded sender.

Third, a design feature of the standard Python implementation is that only *one thread at a time* can be executing Python bytecode. So it is not certain that threading will improve performance.

**Edit:**

There are several ways to run stuff in parallel in Python. There is `multiprocessing.Pool` which uses processes, and `multiprocessing.dummy.ThreadPool` which uses threads. And from Python 3.2 onwards there is `concurrent.futures`, which can use processes or threads.

The thing is, neither of them has rate limiting. So you could get blocked for making too many calls.
Every time you call `SendJsonViaSession` you'd have to save the current time somehow so that all processes or threads can use it. And before every call, you would have to read that time and wait if it is too close to the last call.

**Edit2:**

If a call to `SendJsonViaSession` only takes 0.3 seconds, you should be able to do 3 calls/second sequentially. But your code only does 1 call/second. This implies that the speed restriction is somewhere else. You'd have to [profile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/) your code to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the quick and informative help. I can make 250 calls in 10 seconds, otherwise the throttle starts and i get blocked. Right now i am sending around 10 calls in 10 seconds. So there maybe would be potential for improvement.

Comment: @LeoldeWire And how long does a call to `SendJsonViaSession` actually take?

Comment: ~0.3 seconds i would say

Comment: @LeoldeWire Run your code through a [line profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/). That way you can see which lines actually take the longest time to run. Then you know *what* to optimize